# Not able to hide/show the div on mouse click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div contents of which are dynamically generated.
I am trying to implement hide/show facility.
It kinda works but I am looking at "Hide/show only the div that's clicked."

**HTML**

```
<div class="showmenu">First Div</div>
<div class="menu" style="display: none;">
    <ul>
        <li>Val1</li>
        <li>Val2</li>
        <li>val3</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="showmenu">Second Div</div>
<div class="menu" style="display: none;">
    <ul>
        <li>val4</li>
        <li>val5</li>
        <li>val6</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.showmenu').click(function() {
            $('.menu').slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iamsajeev/APA2S/4499/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use relative looks up for the `menu` item, instead of a document wide look up(`$('.menu')`).

In your case the `showmenu` and `menu` items are next siblings, so you can use [.next()](https://api.jquery.com/next)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.showmenu').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.menu').slideToggle("fast");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="showmenu">First Div</div>
<div class="menu" style="display: none;">
  <ul>
    <li>Val1</li>
    <li>Val2</li>
    <li>val3</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="showmenu">Second Div</div>
<div class="menu" style="display: none;">
  <ul>
    <li>val4</li>
    <li>val5</li>
    <li>val6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to find the `.menu` element related to the element which was clicked. To do that you can traverse from the element that raised the event using the `this` keyword and the `next()` method. Try this:

```
$('.showmenu').click(function () {
    $(this).next('.menu').slideToggle("fast");
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/APA2S/4501/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `this`:

`$(this)` inside the click event handler is the menu that is clicked. `next` will give menu associated with it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.showmenu').click(function() {
        $(this).next('.menu').slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/APA2S/4502/

Answer (score 1):

Use `.next()` in jquery and `$(this)` for current object

```
$('.showmenu').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.menu').slideToggle("fast");
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/APA2S/4503/)

Comment: @albertJegani - soluda karuppu perazhaga

Answer (score 1):

Your looking for jQuery [next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.showmenu').click(function() {
            $(this).next('.menu').slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="showmenu">First Div</div>
<div class="menu" style="display: none;">
    <ul>
        <li>Val1</li>
        <li>Val2</li>
        <li>val3</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="showmenu">Second Div</div>
<div class="menu" style="display: none;">
    <ul>
        <li>val4</li>
        <li>val5</li>
        <li>val6</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```